# Is there a way to lock your Apple device against syncing on other computers?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, ipod-touch

Find my iPhone is nice, but that doesn't really stop savvy thieves from syncing the device back to factory settings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.  That's a flaw of the iPhone that is designed to help you, in case you ever forget your passcode.

Comment: I guess it makes sense.